# How do I fix this python loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
outcome=input("higher or lower")

while (outcome!= 'h' or outcome!= 'l'): 
    outcome=input("enter h or l")

print("its working")
```

the while loop keeps going even when i write H or L

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `and` rather than `or`.

Let's assume the lowercase/uppercase issue is not a problem and you enter `h` rather than `H`.

Your expression will then be:

```
'h' != 'h' or 'h' != 'l'
\________/    \________/
   false   or    true
   \________________/
         true
```

Since an object *cannot* be two things at once, one of those inequalities must be true. Hence the entire expression must be true.

Hence you should change it to something like:

```
while (outcome != 'h') and (outcome != 'l'):
```

or:

```
while outcome not in ('h', 'l'):
```

the latter being more succinct as the number of possibilities increases:

```
while outcome not in ('n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'u', 'd', 'l', 'r'):
```

Comment: yes thank you. i should have double checked before posting.
thanks again :)

Comment: Another option: `while outcome not in ('h', 'l'):`

Comment: I would recomment @StevenRumbalski's answer, that I think that would be more pythonic way to do it